# Web page moves horizonatally in the Iphone 7

Tags: html, css

I see that the website home page horizontally moves when a user scrolls the page.
Below is the URL:
https://tandcity.dk/da/

I have tried the below CSS

```
body{
overflow: hidden;
}

html{
overflow: hidden;
}
```

I added some meta tags. You can check on view source.

Can someone please help me to fix this.

Comment: Rashmi kindly provides proper HTML code here so we can understand and resolve your question.

Comment: i think u also need to assign width and height so overflow can be done maybe for body width:100vw; height:100vh;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this from body tag:

```
body {
/* overflow: hidden; */
/* width: 100vw; */
/* height: 100vh; */
}
```

**For Mobile:**

On this class `.vc_grid.vc_row.vc_grid-gutter-15px .vc_pageable-slide-wrapper` remove `margin-right: -15px` replace with `margin-right: 0px` if you want to.

Afrter that replace `.vc_grid.vc_row.vc_grid-gutter-15px .vc_grid-item` , `padding-right: 15px;` with `padding-right: 0px;`

Remember for this mobile chages to take affect you have to add it within an `@media` query.

Example: Where you add the custom css, add this before the closing  tag

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { 

   .vc_grid.vc_row.vc_grid-gutter-15px .vc_pageable-slide-wrapper {
       margin-right: 0px;
 }

  .vc_grid.vc_row.vc_grid-gutter-15px .vc_grid-item {
      padding-right: 0px;
 }

}
```

**For iphone 7 :**

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
  @media only screen 
   and (min-device-width: 414px) 
   and (max-device-width: 736px) 
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

   .vc_grid.vc_row.vc_grid-gutter-15px .vc_pageable-slide-wrapper {
       margin-right: 0px;
 }

  .vc_grid.vc_row.vc_grid-gutter-15px .vc_grid-item {
      padding-right: 0px;
 }
}
```

Comment: I have removed. This problem is there only on mobile.

Comment: @RashmiSonke i think my latest one would work the margin is moving the block out of body width.

Comment: @RashmiSonke im going to give you an exaple of a @ media query becuase the way you added it has an influence on desktop, it should only effect mobile, also remeber to remove padding aswell , looks much better.

Comment: Can you please also up vote the answer so it is marked as solved, thanks.